# can I block "Add Event" in @aldabil/react-scheduler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, calendar

i need to block the Add Event in the [@aldabil/react-scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aldabil/react-scheduler) package

My Code :

```
<Scheduler
        // height={400}
        events={events}
        editable={false}
        deletable={false}
        view={'month'}
        day={{
          startHour: 0,
          endHour: 24,
          step: 60,
          navigation: true,
        }}
        week={{
          startHour: 0,
          endHour: 24,
          step: 60,
          navigation: true,
        }}
      />
```